# PHP: Dealing with function case-insensitivity

Tags: php, class, case-sensitive

I have a situation where there are similar functions in different classes, let's call them "Execute" and "execute."

```
class oldVersion {
    public function Execute($x){
        echo 'This does the same thing as newVersion->execute(1)';
        echo 'but the class contains a lot of garbage that PHP7 doesn\'t like.';
        echo 'and the app dies if it\'s included';
    }
}

class newVersion {
    public function execute($x, $y = 0, $z = 0){
        if($y == 1){
            echo 'do thing one';
        } else {
            echo 'do thing zero';
        }
        return 'bar';
    }
}
$obj1 = new oldVersion();
$obj1->Execute('foo');

$obj2 = new newVersion();
$obj2->execute('bar', 1);
```

The class oldVersion has a lot of things wrong with it and won't function at all under PHP7, so what I'd really love to be able to do is move Execute into newVersion and do this:

```
class oldVersion_deprecated {
    // no longer included so PHP7 doesn't break
}

class newVersion {
    public function Execute($x){
        return $this->execute($x, 1);
    }
    public function execute($x, $y = 0, $z = 0){
        if($y == 1){
            echo 'do thing one';
        } else {
            echo 'do thing two';
        }
        return 'bar';
    }
}

$obj1 = new newVersion();
$obj1->Execute('foo');

$obj2 = new newVersion();
$obj2->execute('bar', 1);
```

But naturally I get

```
FATAL ERROR: cannot redefine execute
```

Is there a fancy workaround, or am I stuck finding and rewriting every call?

Comment: Time for some re-writing :(

Comment: Yeah, was afraid of that. I had hope. Briefly.

Comment: Well, I'm clearly an ocd coder, so that existence of an issue would already be forcing me down a path of mass-search and editing code to clean it all up ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit messy, and I wouldn't normally recommend it, but you can simulate case-sensitive methods with PHP's "magic" [`__call`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) method. This gets called whenever a method can't be found in the given class. You can then check the supplied method name, and run whatever logic is appropriate.

```
class Foo
{
    public function __call($name, $args)
    {
        switch ($name) {
            case 'Execute':
                return $this->oldExecute(...$args);
            case 'execute':
                return $this->newExecute(...$args);
        }
    }

    private function oldExecute($x)
    {
        echo 'Running old function with arg: ', $x, PHP_EOL;
    }

    private function newExecute($x, $y, $z)
    {
        echo 'Running new function with args: ', implode(',', [$x, $y, $z]), PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

See https://eval.in/926262

Comment: Messy, yes, but bears looking into. That would at least let me remove the old library and keep going, and then back fill the correct way as time permits.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. It can be a useful stop-gap if it gets you a bit further down the road to refactoring properly. But the fact it exposes a confusing class API (do I need to call *Execute* or *execute*...), and makes the class less self-documenting is a pretty big downside. All comes down to your specific case.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the first execute function that calls the "real" one. Functions are case insensitive so you dont have to have two

```
class newVersion {
 public function execute($x, $y = 0, $z = 0){
    if($y == 1){
        echo 'do thing one';
    } else {
        echo 'do thing two';
    }
    return 'bar';
   }
 }
 /* All the same */
 echo newv->Execute('foo');
 echo newv->ExEcUTe('foo');  
 echo newv->execute('bar', 1);
```

Comment: Considered that, but the $y parameter is significant and greatly affects the outcome - and is already defaulted to a value that isn't useful to the *other* Execute function.